# A Problem about the Differentiability and Directional Derivative

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following problem:

> Assume that $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ satisfies $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le M\cdot|x-y|$$for some $M\in \Bbb R$ and $f(0)=0$. Suppose that all the directional derivatives vanish at the origin. Prove that  $f$ is differentiable at 0.

The following was what I tried: 
In order to show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$, we need to find a linear map $A$ such that $$\lim_{h\to0}{{|f(h)-f(0)-A\cdot h|}\over{|h|}}=0.$$ 
Since all the directional derivatives vanish at 0, which says $A=0$ (Is this right???).
$0\le{{|f(h)-f(0)|}\over{|h|}}\le M|h|/|h|=M$, which I cannot get the desired result. Any help, please.

Comment: This is true. Your map is linear and telling that everything is zero. To understand more on this you may want to check Lipschitz condition.

Answer (score 2):

The given assumptions indeed imply that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and that $df(0)=0$.

*Proof.* We have to prove that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}{|f(x)|\over|x|}=0\ .$$
Assume that this is not the case. Then there exists an $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $(x_k)_{k\geq0}$ with $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_k=0$ such that
$$|f(x_k)|>\epsilon |x_k|\qquad\forall k\geq0\ .$$
The unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ is compact. After passing to a subsequence we can therefore assume that there is an $u\in S^{n-1}$ with
$${x_k\over|x_k|}\to u\qquad(k\to\infty)\ .$$
It follows that there is a $k_0$ such that
$$\left|{x_k\over|x_k|}-u\right|<{\epsilon\over 2M}\qquad(k>k_0)\ ,$$
or
$$\biggl|x_k-|x_k|u\biggr|<{\epsilon|x_k|\over 2M}\qquad(k\to\infty)\ .$$
The Lipschitz condition then implies that
$$\biggl|f\bigl(|x_k|u\bigr)\biggr|\geq|f(x_k)|-M\biggl|x_k-|x_k|u\biggr|>\epsilon|x_k|-{\epsilon|x_k|\over 2}={\epsilon|x_k|\over2}\qquad(k>k_0)\ .$$
It follows that
$${\bigl|f\bigl(|x_k|u\bigr)\bigr|\over|x_k|}\geq{\epsilon\over2}$$
for all $k>k_0$, which contradicts the assumption $D_uf(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, the Lipschitz condition applied here is useless. The essence of the problem lies in the difference between the directional derivative definition and this stronger full differentiation definition.

**Edit:** In consideration of the contradiction proof from Christian Blatter, and a few attempts, it appears what I had before probably won't work. Anyway, for a direct proof suggestion, use an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof, and apply the definition of directional derivative to **many** different directions. Then for a given direction $h$, you can compare to the result to the nearest one for which you have applied the definition. Probably in essence will be the same as Christian's proof.